# Javascript & back button

Tags: javascript, back-button, back

My question is how I can use the back button of the browser to reverse i.e. a DOM...
Here's another example: I have a function, which edits the color of a text from black to blue. Now I want, that when the back button is pressed, the text will be black again.

An code example would be nice ;)
Thx and greetings Franz

Comment: I think you are asking about  document.getElementById or  document.getElementByClassNmae .. see I have given answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code: It will work I have tried it now.

```
 <html>
<body>

<div id="demo">Click me to change my text color.</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<script>
var flag=1;
function myFunction() {
flag=flag+1;
if(flag%2==0)
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";
if(flag%2==1)
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "blue";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of the back button is always to fully reload the last page in the history. The only way to override this is by using the browser's [history state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) with the [relatively new HTML5 API for this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

Your color-changing function will have to use `history.pushState` to add a new historic state to the browser's history, and you will have to subscribe to the `window.onpopstate` event to handle the back button correctly afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the undo button of the browser to do this in your program. This button link you to the previous page.

But you can remember the old value in some variable and after the user hits your back button change the value of your text to the old one.

Answer (score -1):

Can't what you're asking be done with pure CSS?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp